# Beep only when MiFare 1k card is fully read by ACR122U reader

Tags: c#, smartcard, mifare

If the card is removed immediately after beep it generates an error.

I only want UID of card; if card is kept, it works but we tend to remove card as soon as we hear beep.
In short I want to delay the beep, so card is not removed before getting read completely.

```
public bool connectCard()
    {
        connActive = true;

        retCode = Card.SCardConnect(hContext, readername, Card.SCARD_SHARE_SHARED,
                  Card.SCARD_PROTOCOL_T0 | Card.SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1, ref hCard, ref Protocol);

        if (retCode != Card.SCARD_S_SUCCESS)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Card.GetScardErrMsg(retCode), "Card not available");
            connActive = false;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
 private string getcardUID()        //only for mifare 1k cards
    {
        string cardUID = "";
        byte[] receivedUID = new byte[256];
        Card.SCARD_IO_REQUEST request = new Card.SCARD_IO_REQUEST();
        request.dwProtocol = Card.SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1;

        request.cbPciLength = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Card.SCARD_IO_REQUEST));


        byte[] sendBytes = new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xCA, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};         //get UID command      for Mifare cards
        int outBytes = receivedUID.Length;

        int status = Card.SCardTransmit(hCard, ref request, ref sendBytes[0], sendBytes.Length, ref request, ref receivedUID[0], ref outBytes);

        if (status != Card.SCARD_S_SUCCESS)
        {
            cardUID = "Error";

        }
        else
        {
            cardUID = BitConverter.ToString(receivedUID.Take(7).ToArray()).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLower();
        }

        return cardUID;
    }
```

Comment: I am new.I didnt know how to edit,i was editing can u wait a bit before down voting?

Comment: @SahilDombe Try with another reader u have. ACR take time to read the card for first time plug with device. I faced the same issue then i use the another reader(ASK reader) its working fine.

Comment: @sk2185 atleast delay the beep or put it hold for few secs

Comment: Since your code does not show any attempt to issue a beep, it has to be the reader or matching driver. Refer to the Manual or at least try another reader as suggested by @sk2185.